# Pass Collection of Object from Controller to View Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Whenever i m passing data from Controller to View this error is showing

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[CaliberCoaching.Models.CareerInformation]'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[CaliberCoaching.Models.CareerInformation]'.
```

This is My Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult JobList()
        {
            CaliberCoachingContext objCaliberCoachingContext = new CaliberCoachingContext();
            var lstCareerInformation = (from job in objCaliberCoachingContext.CareerInformations
                                                            select new { job.NameOfPost, job.PostName, job.StartDate, job.LastDate, job.Eligibility, job.NoOfVacancies }).ToList();

            return View(lstCareerInformation);
        }
```

and here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<CaliberCoaching.Models.CareerInformation>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "JobList";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CommonLayout.cshtml";
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="single-item-wrapper">

        <div class="courses-content-wrapper">
            <h3 class="title-default-left-bold">@item.NameOfPost</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Please Give me the solution for this Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is self explanatory! Your razor view is strongly typed to a collection of `CareerInformation` objects, but from your action method, you are passing a different type to the view!

In your action method, the variable `lstCareerInformation` is not a collection of `CareerInformation` objects, but a collection of **anonymous** objects. This is happening because your LINQ expression is doing a projection to an annonymous object.

```
 select new { job.NameOfPost, job.PostName, job.StartDate,
              job.LastDate, job.Eligibility, job.NoOfVacancies }
```

*`select new` will create an anonymous object*

To fix the error, you should return a collection of `CareerInformation` objects. Just remove the projection part from your LINQ expression.

```
public ActionResult JobList()
{
    var db = new CaliberCoachingContext();
    var careerInformationList = db.CareerInformations.ToList();
    return View(careerInformationList);
}
```

*EDIT : As per the comment*

> i have used anonymous object because i wants to select particular
>   columns instead of all the columns from CareerInformation properties.

Then you should be using a view model. Create a viewmodel class with properties needed in your view.

```
public class JobVm
{
   public string PostName { set;get;}
   public Eligibility { set;get;}
   public DateTime StartDate { set;get;}
   // Add other properties needed by the view 
}
```

Now in your action method, project create view model objects from your entity object collection using the `Select` method.

```
public ActionResult JobList()
{
    var db = new CaliberCoachingContext();
    var careerInformationList = db.CareerInformations
                                  .Select(a=> new JobVm { PostName = a.PostName,
                                                          StartDate = a.StartDate,
                                                          Eligibility = a.Eligibility })
                                  .ToList();
    return View(careerInformationList);
}
```

Here `careerInformationList` is a list of `JobVm`  objects and that is what we are passing to the View. So make sure your view is strongly typed to a collection of the `JobVm` objects.

```
@model List<JobVm>
<h2>Jobs</h2>
@foreach(var job in Model)
{
   <div>@job.PostName</div>
   <p>@job.Eligibility</p>
}
```

Comment: i have used anonymous object because i wants to select particular columns instead of all the columns from **CareerInformation** properties.

Comment: Then you should be using a view model. See the updated answer.